How to resolve ‘The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage’?
I am currently trying to run a kubernetes job. The job has several pods, and these pods run on 3 different nodes. I am constantly running into This issue -
Message: The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Threshold quantity: 7898109241, available: 7706460Ki. Container job_script was using 9227112Ki, request is 2Gi, has larger consumption of ephemeral-storage.
Here are the logs:
Name:             job_script-job-jlkz2
Namespace:        default
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             <Hostname>/<IP>
Start Time:       Thu, 19 Sep 2024 11:22:41 -0400
Labels:           app=job_script
                  batch.kubernetes.io/controller-uid=f83e0818-3633-436f-961b-19e5cc834deb
                  batch.kubernetes.io/job-name=job_script-job
                  controller-uid=f83e0818-3633-436f-961b-19e5cc834deb
                  job-name=job_script-job
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 6e5f7117c18a6623c5c7c8c83269f9f9b06aaa360a76c184a33f32602cc1bacf
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP:
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs:
Status:           Failed
Reason:           Evicted
Message:          The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Threshold quantity: 7898109241, available: 7706460Ki. Container job_script was using 9227112Ki, request is 2Gi, has larger consumption of ephemeral-storage.
IP:               <IP>
IPs:
  IP:           <IP>
Controlled By:  Job/job_script-job
Containers:
  job_script:
    Container ID:
    Image:         ghcr.io/<username>/job_script:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      ./job_script > /scripts/logs/job_script.out 2> /scripts/logs/job_script.err & while true; do cp -r /scripts/fs-state/ /scripts/host-persistent-volume/; sleep 1; done
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerStatusUnknown
      Message:      The container could not be located when the pod was terminated
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       ContainerStatusUnknown
      Message:      The container could not be located when the pod was deleted.  The container used to be Running
      Exit Code:    137
      Started:      Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000
      Finished:     Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      cpu:                1
      ephemeral-storage:  30Gi
      memory:             2Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:                1
      ephemeral-storage:  2Gi
      memory:             200Mi
    Environment:          <none>
    Mounts:
      /dev/ram0 from ramdisk-volume (rw)
      /scripts/host-persistent-volume from persistent-volume (rw)
      /scripts/include from include-volume (rw)
      /scripts/logs from logs-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-b4khn (ro)
Conditions:
  Type                        Status
  DisruptionTarget            True
  PodReadyToStartContainers   False
  Initialized                 True
  Ready                       False
  ContainersReady             False
  PodScheduled                True
Volumes:
  include-volume:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /mnt/d/folder1/include
    HostPathType:
  logs-volume:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /mnt/d/folder2/script_logs
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  persistent-volume:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /mnt/d/folder2/pan_logs
    HostPathType:  DirectoryOrCreate
  ramdisk-volume:
    Type:          HostPath (bare host directory volume)
    Path:          /dev/ram0
    HostPathType:  BlockDevice
  kube-api-access-b4khn:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   Burstable
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>

When I do a kubectl describe nodes -
Events:

Type Reason Age From Message

Warning FreeDiskSpaceFailed 4m46s kubelet Failed to garbage collect required amount of images. Attempted to free 2255556608 bytes, but only found 0 bytes eligible to free.

I have tried to increase the Ephemeral storage on my YAML file from 10GB to 30 GB, but even that didn't do much. How can I resolve this issue? Is there a way to clean up ephemeral storage on a regular basis?
